# How to search in an array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a schema as below

```
var QuestionListSchema = new Schema({
    topicName: String,
    quesList: {
        quesListName: String,
        by: String,
        questions: [{
            question: String
        }]
    }
});
```

I need to search the question in questions array ;i am doing it by passing search question in params

I have a query as below

```
exports.question = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.quesListName);
    QuestionList.find({
        "quesList.questions":new RegExp(req.query.questions, 'i')
    }, function(err, questionList) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(fnData(questionList));
    });
};
```

but i m unable to get the searched data

Comment: try this QuestionList.find({quesList:{ questions: new RegExp(req.query.questions, 'i') }})

Comment: You forgot to include the field name in the dot notation query `QuestionList.find({
    "quesList.questions.question": new RegExp(req.query.questions, 'i')
}, function(err, questionList) { ... })`

Comment: i got the response but the thing is i m getting whole object instead of the data what i searched